# How to add images in db?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core

Currently working in an intern project, where i am required to add an image when adding an employee in my table.

[image]

[image]

we are using angularJS in front end and asp.net core 3.1 in backend, we have sql database using SSMS, i couldnt get it how to upload images, my senior told me to store the path in db, if i am to store the path in db, where will my images be uploaded, i did upload the images making an api on wwwroot folder, but they marked it as a bad practice? So can any of you guide me? Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Not directly in the wwwroot folder but in a subfolder. Then you should organize  the images in this subfolder (by creating subfolders for branches, roles etc) and store the path in the db. You could also create an unique folder with unique filenames for each image (using a guid for example)

Answer (score 0):

Steve's Comment is useful. You can upload image to the new folder under the wwwroot. [You can refer the blog fisrt, it create a `Resources` folder, and it also use angular.](https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/)

---

#### In general, we still do not recommend storing pictures under wwwroot. Regardless of whether you create a subfolder such as Sources.

*Reason：*

1. As the business increases, or over time, the contents under the folder will definitely increase. Even if the hard disk space at the deployment site is large, it will cause subsequent maintenance problems.
2. Specifically, the picture file may be accidentally deleted and cannot be recovered subsequently. If the picture file ends up taking up a lot of space, it will run out of hard disk space.

**The Best Practice:**

Upload the image to the cloud drive, something like: [azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction). And save the path to your database. It will save your disk space and it will also relieve your server stress, and more safety.

---

Additional tips:

If you just store a very small avatar file, we can convert it to base64 string format and store it in the database. In the absence of cloud services, some tiny images can be realized in this way.

However, this is not suitable for growing business scenarios, because it will cause the database footprint to become larger, which is not conducive to synchronization or backup. As well as poor large files, it may cause problems with the loading of files.